# Are there any free chatbots that can do CRUD operation in database

Tags: php, mysql, chatbot

I am doing a school project for our school's open house using php and mysql, and we need a chatbot that can help our guests create a queue number so that they can visit our teachers. Are there any free chatbots around that you can suggest that is able to do CRUD operations in a database? We are hoping to create something like an appointment system in the chatbot.

Thank you so much for your help